# Cannot run .py files outside of cgi-bin

Tags: python, apache, mod-python

I'm at my wits end trying to figure out why I can't run .py files outside of my cgi-bin directory. I installed mod_python, and was able to successfully run .py files after setting up my sites-available/default file as follows in Apache2:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

The code above only allows me to run .py files inside the cgi-bin.

From what I understand, I don't want to use CGI to run python, because it's not efficient. I'm trying to follow [this](http://www.howtoforge.com/embedding-python-in-apache2-with-mod_python-debian-etch) tutorial, and in doing so, I have modified my sites-available/default file to the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
          AddHandler mod_python .py
          PythonHandler mod_python.publisher
          PythonDebug On
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

After modifying my sites-available/default to the code above, every .py file I try to run from a browser returns a 404 error. Permissions are 755 for all .py files I have found.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Showing a particular request URL and the errorlog entry it generates would be helpful

Comment: Step 1: [Stop using mod_python.](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/06/modpython-project-is-now-officially.html) Step 2: Get mod_wsgi.

Comment: @covener Request URL: ipaddress/test.py

Error:
[Sat Feb 15 13:15:38 2014] [notice] mod_python (pid=2698, interpreter='vps.server.com'): Importing module '/var/www/test.py'
[Sat Feb 15 13:15:38 2014] [error] [client 50.162.38.135] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Sat Feb 15 13:15:38 2014] [error] [client 50.162.38.135] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico

Comment: Doesn't look like a 404 was generated for /test.py from httpd. Maybe mod_python did that and didn't log a message.